# Css selector for bootstrap popover not working

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

in my css file I want to target the ul tag inside the popover. So I tried

```
.myClass ul {list-style: none;}
```

But it's not working. If I use .popover ul {...} it's working. But I want for different classes, different styles. So how can I select for a specific class the ul tag inside the bootstrap popover? 
My popover code is:

```
<span class="myClass" data-html="true" data-toggle="popover" title="myTitle" data-content="<ul><li>This is a test</li></ul>">myPopover</span>
```

Or is the only way to give the ul tag a class?

Comment: its not working means ? you are not seeing it in inspect ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will this work for you? Use general sibling selector on `myClass`.

```js
$(function() {
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()
})
```

```css
.myClass ~ .popover ul {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<span class="myClass" data-html="true" data-toggle="popover" title="myTitle" data-content="<ul><li>This is a test</li></ul>">myPopover</span>
```

Comment: thank you, looks like ~ did the trick. I have to learn about ~

Answer (score 0):

In bootsrap 4, the popover div is not a child element of the popover toggle. The popover div is added in by javascript probably as a direct child of the "body" element. So you cannot style it with the class added to the span element.

However if you inspect your span element from your browser dev tools, you should see an extra attribute `aria-describedby="{{popover-id}}"` added to the element. You should be able to (with javascript) access that property using the class name and hopefully copy the styles from the class and add it to the popover element using the id.

In conclusion, adding a class to the ul tag is the easier way.

Comment: thank you for your answer and explanation. But it looks like the ~ is working ( .myClass ~ .popover ul ).

Comment: @OliverHD, that only works because you are making use of a general sibling selector. The popover div is a sibling of the span.Using that selector would match all popover siblings of the span whether or not it is toggled by the span.

Comment: thank you for the explanation. I will def. keep the popover-id in mind.